# How to remove WLAN Configuration Software

Tags: windows-xp

I have with me Wireless adaptor. After first time installing it i have removed it from computer without add or remove program by simply right click delete. Now i am installing again but at the time of installation it shows one message "Another WLAN configuration software exist in your system. That could cause problem. Please Uninstall it first". I have removed some registation keys as per u suggested. Still at the time of installation that error continues. Please suggest me what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall the wireless program that is causing the problem. Then uninstall it properly.